# Payload length of x bytes exceeds the allowed limit of 8192 bytes

Tags: autodesk-designautomation

Is there a way to increase the max size of the workitem in the post request? I have 7 parameters, that means 7 aws presigned url, hence the workitem size during the post.

Answer (score 0):

Your pre-signed URLs are "abnormally long" because they include x-amz-security-token. Pre-signed URLs are already temporary (contain an expiration) so I'm not sure why you are using temporary credentials to generate them.

Can you look into this?

Comment: I'm using the aws sdk to generate them, so they probably add everything on their own. I'll check if I can do anything about it.

Comment: It seems our poor aws organization requires us to assume role in the aws configuration. So, it always generates token field for the presigned url. I won't be able to fix that...

Comment: Sorry about the late response. I see. We can adjust this. Please request this via the regular developer support channel and provide your clientId.